# R: Filling the NULLs in a data column

Tags: r, rstudio

The data I'm working on looks like this:

```
          timestamp switchOnOff speed speedlimit
2015-03-26 20:00:00        NULL  NULL         35
2015-03-26 20:15:00        NULL    41         35
2015-03-26 20:30:00           0    49         35
2015-03-26 20:45:00           1  NULL         35
2015-03-26 21:00:00         Yes  NULL       NULL
2015-03-26 21:15:00        NULL  NULL         35
2015-03-26 21:30:00          No  NULL       NULL
2015-03-26 21:45:00           5    51         40
```

For variable:
`switchOnOff: 0, 1`;
-but it also has many other levels which I'm trying to covert into 0, 1 only. I tried the following for-loop, which does not work because of the `NULLs (empty, length = 0)`:

```
for (i in 1:length(timestamp)) {
  if (is.null(switchOnOff[i]) | switchOnOff[i] == "Yes") {
    switchOnOff[i] = 1
  } else if (switchOnOff[i] == "No") {
      switchOnOff[i] = 0
  } else if (switchOnOff[i] >= 1){
      switchOnOff[i] = 1
  } else {switchOnOff[i] = switchOnOff[i]}
}
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows a better way solving this kind of Null-filling problems? Also, is there a way to import data into R without ignoring the `NULLs` so the data will stay in the exact position as they should? Many Thanks!

M

Comment: Please provide the `dput` of your dataset.  I am guessing the `NULL` to be character element.   Also, the expected output based on the example data.

Comment: you could perhaps use: switchOnOff[switchOnOff=="Yes"]<-1 , and for "no" same rule with "0". What do you want to do with the NULLs in the end?

Comment: @akrun Actually all 'NULLs' are just empty...The data was pulled from the database...

Comment: @YMing That's what I thought also.  Anyway, please do post the `dput` output and the expected result. i.e. `dput(head(yourdata,10))`

Comment: @RuthgerRighart What I was trying to realize is: for each timestamp, if the corresponding switchOnOff is NULL, then fill it as 1. The problem is when switchOnOff is NULL, it is actually empty and I wasn't able to use a loop to get the switchOnOff[i] since it doesn't exist..

Comment: If it's empty, you can try `if(switchOnOff[i] == "") {}`

Comment: @akrun Molx Thank you guys very much. Well, the original data is in JSON format and I just ended up ignoring the `nulls` and let the DBA and other guys to do the enumeration and hydrate the `nulls`....